# Bash script can't find another file when ran through puppet module?

Tags: bash, module, puppet, ethereum

I created puppet script that downloads ethereum miner from my github and it works nicely, but when I try to use exec to start the miner it complains that there is no such file as ./ethdcrminer64 even though it is in the folder and I can run the script manually.

The not working part of the module looks like this:

```
file {'miner_skripti':
    ensure => 'file',
    path => '/tmp/puppetethereum/claymore/mine.sh',
    notify => Exec['run_miner'],
}

exec { 'run_miner':
    command => 'bash /tmp/puppetethereum/claymore/mine.sh',
    provider => 'shell',
}
```

And the error message I get looks like this:

```
Error: /tmp/puppetethereum/claymore/mine.sh: line 13: ./ethdcrminer64: No such file or directory

Error: /Stage[main]/Ethereum/Exec[run_miner]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /tmp/puppetethereum/claymore/mine.sh: line 13: ./ethdcrminer64: No such file or directory
```

I know for a fact that ./ethdcrminer64 is in the folder and that it works, because I can run it with bash from terminal, but for some reason it doesn't work through puppet.

Edit. This is on puppet version 3.8.5

Comment: Set `cwd` to the directory that `ethdcrminer64` is in.

Comment: @jordanm Thank you! That worked. Now I just gotta figure out how to stop puppet from waiting for it to finish ('cause it will never finish) and maybe find how to show the terminal on agent where it was run, but thank you very much. I would upvote you, but you submitted this as comment and not an answer.

Comment: You could try starting the mine.sh script in the background. `command => 'bash /tmp/.../mine.sh &',`

Comment: If you don't want to end up with multiple copies of your script running, then maybe what you *really* want to do is dress it up as a service with an initscript or whatever other dressing is needed for your system, and have puppet install it and manage it as one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's apparently what I need. Could you link me to something that would push me to right direction? This is for a school project and I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: Different systems do service management differently.  [This article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/lsbinit-script/) gives a brief overview of the traditional Unix method, but your system may well do it differently.  Consult system-specific documentation.  Once you figure out how to set up a service, you can use Puppet to install (`Package`, `File`, etc.) and manage it (`Service`).